# problem in finding the calculated auc and aupr values

Tags: r, machine-learning, clustering

This is the code for k-seeds clustering where features and side_effects are the excel files. I am facing problem in understanding the results. Where to find the calculated AUC and AUPR values? And what does this implies `(list(AUCFinal,AUPRFinal))` where, first value is the mean AUC on the various folders, second value is the mean AUPR on the various folders.
the code is -

```
#vectors where the means of the AUC will be stored
vectorMedieAUC<-numeric()
#vectors where the means of the AUPR will be stored
vectorMedieAUPR<-numeric()

#various Iterations of the k-folds cross validation procedure
for(j in 1:num_iterations){
  i=0 # variable to trace that is the first time of the k-fold cross validation procedure
  vectorAUC<-numeric() #instantiate a vecotr of AUC for first iteration of the k-fold cross validation procedure
  vectorAUPR<-numeric() # vector of AUPR for first iteration of the k-folds cross validation procedure

  folds<-CreateFolds(features,num_folds)
  train = features[folds != i,]
  trainpharmat = side_effects[folds != i,]
  test = features[folds == i,]
  testpharmat = side_effects[folds == i,]

  #KSeeds clustering method application
  s<-RandomSeedGenerator(num_clusters,nrow(train)) #function that generates randomly the numbers that will be the seeds of the cluster
  Seed<-SeedSelection(train,num_clusters,s)
  #Return the list of clusters
  clusters<-KSeedsClusters (train,num_clusters,Seed,s)
  #Return the matrix A of KSeeds scores
  A<-KSeedsScores(train,trainpharmat,num_clusters,Seed,s,clusters)

  #KSeeds predictions for drugs in the test set
  predizioni<-PredictionKSeeds(test,Seed,num_clusters,A)

  #Function for obtaining AUC
  vectorAUC<-AUC(predizioni,testpharmat,vectorAUC,"KSeeds")

  #Function for obtaining AUPR
  vectorAUPR<-AUPR(predizioni,testpharmat,vectorAUPR,"KSeeds")

  for(i in 1:(num_folds-1)){
    train = features[folds != i,]
    trainpharmat = side_effects[folds != i,]
    test = features[folds == i,]
    testpharmat = side_effects[folds == i,]

    #KSeeds clustering
    s<-RandomSeedGenerator(num_clusters,nrow(train)) #function that generates randomly the numbers that will be the seeds of the cluster
    Seed<-SeedSelection(train,num_clusters,s)

    #Return the list of clusters
    clusters<-KSeedsClusters (train,num_clusters,Seed,s)
    #Return the matrix A of KSeeds scores
    A<-KSeedsScores(train,trainpharmat,num_clusters,Seed,s,clusters)





    #KSeeds predictions for drugs in the test set
    predizioni<-PredictionKSeeds(test,Seed,num_clusters,A)

    #Function for obtaining AUC
    vectorAUC<-AUC(predizioni,testpharmat,vectorAUC,"KSeeds")

    #Function for obtaining AUPR
    vectorAUPR<-AUPR(predizioni,testpharmat,vectorAUPR,"KSeeds")
  }
  vectorMedieAUC<-c(vectorMedieAUC,mean(vectorAUC))
  vectorMedieAUPR <-c(vectorMedieAUC,mean(vectorAUPR))
  j=j+1

}

AUCFinal<-mean(vectorMedieAUC)
AUPRFinal<-mean(vectorMedieAUPR)
return(list(AUCFinal,AUPRFinal))

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The calculated values are what you compute the means from:

```
AUCFinal<-mean(vectorMedieAUC)
AUPRFinal<-mean(vectorMedieAUPR)
```

But somehow I have the impression that you googled some code that you do not understand... But then, on the other hand, it's from a pretty dead R package that like many other R packages breaks with most programming conventions...